# Two ipv6 tunnels on one host

Tags: linux, networking, routing, linux-networking, ipv6

I have host with additional IP addresses. We will call them as 51.52.53.54 and 71.72.73.74 and two ipv6 tunnels with /48 subnets.

Tunnel provider gives example configuration and I configured my first tunnel as:

```
auto he-ipv6
iface he-ipv6 inet6 v4tunnel
        address 2001:470:a1b1:xxxx::2
        netmask 64
        endpoint 216.66.80.30
        local 51.52.53.54
        ttl 255
        gateway 2001:470:a1b1:xxxx::1
```

After firing it up tunnel is working.

I can add to this **he-ipv6** device as many ipv6 addresses as I want and they all work.

So I configured second tunnel with this info:

```
auto he-ipv6-2
iface he-ipv6-2 inet6 v4tunnel
        address 2001:470:c2d2:xxxx::2
        netmask 64
        endpoint 216.66.84.46
        local 71.72.73.74
        ttl 255
        gateway 2001:470:c2d2:xxxx::1
```

And when I try to ping, traceroute or tcpdump any IP from this subnet I see nothing.

Though, if I turn down my first tunnel on local ip 51.52.53.54, then my second tunnel on local ip 71.72.73.74 work!

I rechecked tons of information about routing and tried various things, but still unlucky.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

HE is likely filtering the traffic arriving on tunnels to make sure the source address matches with the network allocation.

Now, from your side it looks like the default route is pointing to the first tunnel. When you try to ping anything from the PC assigned the network from the second tunnel it will go through the first tunnel (this is how the regular routing works) anyway and will be dropped dead on the floor by filtering on the incoming tunnel. When you close the tunnel, routing table will change as the previous default route gets deleted and default route for the second tunnel now gets used and traffic gets through.

You can work around this using policy based routing and having a look at `ip-rule` and `ip-route` man pages. `ip rule` command will let you select routing table based on source IP/IPv6 address and `ip route` will let you build alternate routing table.